# SQL - how to replace a range of datetimes with a single, future datetime?

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, replace, sqlcommand

This is a basic SQL datetime question, but I don't want to mess my database up!

For example, in a MySQL database, if I want to replace all datetime values between date X and date Y in a single column in one of my tables - what's the SQL command to do it? Example: I want to replace all datetime values in January of this month with a future date/time in March.

I know how to select a range of datetimes thanks to other StackOverflow questions - example:

```
select * from table where DatetimeField between '22/02/2009 09:00:00.000' and '23/05/2009 10:30:00.000'
```

But how to add the replace() function to this?

Thanks in advance for your help - I've made a database backup just in case!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe you can show what it does now and what you would like instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a function, a simple UPDATE statement does the trick. Here is some commented sample SQL code, if I understood your question correctly:

```
UPDATE Table -- Put in your table name
  SET DateTimeField='31/03/2011 10:30:00.000' -- Change to replacement date/time
  WHERE DatetimeField BETWEEN -- This is the time range to replace, 
    '22/02/2009 09:00:00.000' AND '23/05/2009 10:30:00.000' -- inclusive
```

Comment: Doh! You're a star - thanks Michael for the good, concise info.

Answer (score 1):

You use an `update` query to update values in the table. This will filter out the records with the selected dates and put a new date in the field:

```
update table
set DatetimeField = '01/03/2009 09:00:00.000'
where DatetimeField between '22/02/2009 09:00:00.000' and '23/05/2009 10:30:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET DateTimeField = '2011-03-17'
WHERE DateTimeField >= '2011-01-01'
    and DateTimeField < '2011-02-01'
```

Between is inclusive, so if you want to exclude the exact end date you should use the >= and < syntax.